# Testing BIP47 test vectors

Tags: stealth-address, bip47

[BIP47](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0047.mediawiki) is a new secret-sharing protocol which succeeds [BIP64](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0064.mediawiki) (stealth addresses).

The [test vectors are here](https://gist.github.com/SamouraiDev/6aad669604c5930864bd).

I am stuck on part `2.iv`. We multiply `S0 = B0 * a0` (`024ce8e3b04ea205ff49f529950616c3db615b1e37753858cc60c1ce64d17e2ad8 *  8d6a8ecd8ee5e0042ad0cb56e3a971c760b5145c3917a8e7beaf0ed92d7a520c = 03f5bb84706ee366052471e6139e6a9a969d586e5fe6471a9b96c3d8caefe86fef`).

From that we are looking for:

```
s = HMAC-SHA512(x, o)
"x" is the x value of the secret point
"o" is the outpoint being spent by the first pubkey-exposing input of the transaction.
```

What does `HMAC-SHA512(x, o)` mean, first of all? What is `o` specifically? And how does this factor in with the test vector values?

Comment: I've just had a thought: is it as simple as being the notation for `HMAC-SHA512(passphrase, salt)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the creator of BIP47 (Justus Ranvier), it's RFC2014 notation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Definition_.28from_RFC_2104.29

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104